# Запись кириллицы в .txt функцией fprinf без преобразования в иероглифы

Tags: c

Нужно что бы в конце программы,все введенные данные записывались в файл формата txt. Только они записываются в виде иероглифов. Что можно сделать в такой ситуации? В интернете ничего работающего не нашел.Вводить данные на английском не вариант.

И еще один вопрос - можно ли сделать так,что бы в название файла записывалось значение переменной,а не вводилось вручную? 
Например

```
char name[10] = "Тест";
    FILE *Document; 
Document=fopen("значение переменной Name","w");
```

Comment: Во-первых, где в приведенном коде функция `fprintf`??? Во-вторых, утверждение "записываются в виде иероглифов" - это полная бессмыслица. Никакого "преобразования в иероглифы" функция не `fprintf` не делает. Записанный файл содержит только числа. В каком виде вы *увидите* эти числа зависит только от настроек той программы, которой вы будете просматривать этот файл. Если вы видите там "иероглифы" это означает, что ваш просмотрщик использует неправильную кодировку.

Answer (score 1):

> что бы в название файла записывалось значение переменной

Вот так можно:

```
char name[] = "Тест.txt";
FILE *Document; 
Document=fopen(name,"w");
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался,нужно прописать

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

и все будет нормально

Comment: Бессмыслица полнейшая! Эти вызовы никак не влияют и никак не могут повлиять на то, что именно будет записано в файл.

Comment: Ну Вам виднее! Только у меня все заработало после этого

Comment: Это потому, что реальная проблема не имела абсолютно никакого отношения к записи в файл и к тому, что вы написали в вопросе. Знаете, как в анекдоте: "...не «Волгу», а три рубля. И не в лотерею, а в домино. И не выиграл, а проиграл."